# C# executing if statement every 10 seconds

Tags: c#

I want my code (messagebox) to run no sooner than 10 seconds in this loop timer which is 2000 milliseconds. Is that possible. I want the if statement to be executed every 10 seconds or more but not less even though the loop is 2 seconds.

```
 public void InitBrowser()
        {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 2000;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        t.Start();
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        mycode();
        }

        public async void mycode()
        {
            DateTime SOMETIME = DateTime.Today;
            if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(SOMETIME).TotalSeconds > 10)
            {
                          MessageBox.Show("RUNNED");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Obvious question, but I don't think you've addressed it: if you only want it to run every ten seconds, why is your timer set for every two seconds? Why not just set the timer for ten seconds?

Comment: because the 2 seconds is relavent for other blocks of code. and I cant change that

Comment: Any reason you can't create a separate timer which runs every 10 seconds instead? That seems like the most obvious approach, when you have different bits of code that you want to run on different schedules. (And all of this should be in the question, by the way...)

Comment: i can add another timer, but for learning purpose, I just would like to know if its possible to use Datetime function

Comment: You can set a variable at class level, like `private DateTime lastExecuted = DateTime.Now;` and in `mycode` check seconds between `lastExecuted` and `DateTime.Now` , then refresh  the variable if more than 10

Comment: @Rafalon how would that look like

Comment: If your `Timer` `Ticks` every 2 seconds and you want to do something every 10 seconds then you want to do something every 5 `Ticks`. Can you count to 5?

Comment: I agree with @John. You can run the code (messagebox) every 5th tick.

Comment: Also: `mycode()` should _not_ be `async void`.

Comment: _"but for learning purpose"_... yeah, so let me phrase this question in another context: _"I want to learn to ride my bicycle with my arms crossed, I know you shouldn't do that, but for learning purposes I want to have my arms crossed"_. So the answer is: yes, it possible, but it's bad and can give a lot of problems.

Comment: @HumanBenchmark it would look a bit like Jon's answer below

Comment: Grammar comment: "RUNNED" is not a word. It's either "RAN" or "HAS RUN"  depending on what you want to express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the cleanest way to do this would be to use a timer that ticks every 10 seconds, even if that means having to create a separate one from the timer used by other code.

If you absolutely *must* do it this way, however, you need to keep state (i.e. an instance field) which either keeps track of when you last ran the code, or when you should next run it, or how long it's been since you've run it. If you want to keep using `DateTime`, you should use `DateTime.UtcNow` rather than `DateTime.Now`, otherwise you could well end up with problems around daylight saving time boundaries. Even with `DateTime.UtcNow` you can end up with problems due to the system clock updating - using a `Stopwatch` to keep track of the elapsed time since the last run is probably a better bet. So the code would look something like:

```cs
public class WhateverYourClassIsCalled
{
    private static readonly TimeSpan ExecutionInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    // TODO: Rename to something more meaningful (we don't know what the code does)
    private readonly Stopwatch stopwatch;

    public void InitBrowser()
    {
        stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Timer t = new Timer { Interval = 2000 };
        t.Tick += (sender, args) => HandleTimerTick();
        t.Start();
    }

    // TODO: Avoid async void if possible
    private async void HandleTimerTick()
    {
        if (stopwatch.Elapsed >= ExecutionInterval)
        {
            stopwatch.Restart();
            // Execute your code here
        }
        // Other code here
    }
}
```

Comment: You meant to write InitTimer not InitBrowser?

Comment: theoretically it should probably be "greater or equal to", however, the chance of "equal to" is close to nothing. The question also is which timer to use. .NET6's `PeriodicTimer` seems best suited. And you could also just trigger on each 5th tick, like John said in the comments above.

Comment: @Ralf: I was following the code in the question.

Comment: @JHBonarius: I wouldn't suggest using every fifth tick, as a) that ends up being less clear in terms of intention (it would go wrong if the timer interval changed); b) it relies on knowing the difference between whether there's an interval between the *start* of timer ticks or the end of one timer tick and the start of the next. While it may be fine, I prefer not to have to rely on stuff I'd need to check in the docs, if it's easy to write code which is more "obviously correct".

Comment: Updated to `>=` although as you say I doubt that it would ever make any difference.